# Scheduler not working bug when running spring application with nohup

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, scheduler, nohup

As the title suggests, I ran the spring application in the background with linux nohup, but the scheduler, which should be run every day, doesn't run because the thread died. If you know a solution, please let me know.

API communication works fine
Only the scheduler is weird

Comment: Threads are internal to Java, from the OS point of view the whole app is a single process, so if the API keeps running, the background process is alive. Seems like a problem within the scheduled task itself, try adding log or running the task more often to debug the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.